# In MEL, how do I translate an objects pivot in one direction only?

Tags: 3d, maya, mel

I want to write a script that will take multiple objects, center their respective pivots and then translate the pivots in y to 0.

Here are two variations of my attempts so far:

```
string $sel[] = `ls -sl -typ transform`;
string $obj;

for ($obj in $sel) {
    CenterPivot
    setAttr ($obj + ".scalePivot") -ty 0;
    setAttr ($obj + ".rotatePivot") -ty 0;
}
```

and

```
string $sel[] = `ls -sl -typ transform`;
string $obj;

for ($obj in $sel) {
    xform -cp;
    xform -piv 0 -0.098814 0;
}
```

In the second script the translate y moves to zero (-0.098814 from its start position) but z and x move away from the centre of the source object.

Answer (score 0):

```
string $sel[] = `ls -sl -typ transform`;
string $obj;
for ($obj in $sel)
{
    xform -ws -cp;
    xform -ws -piv 0 -0.098814 0;
}
```

Adding world space will fix your problem I think.

Comment: still ends up off in the distance :/
Sorted anyway now - I centered all of the pivots using the above and then manually snapped them down to the grid

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly:

```
for( $i in `ls -sl`){
    select $i; 
    xform -ws -cp;
    $p = `xform -q -piv -ws`;
    xform -ws -piv $p[0] 0 $p[2];}
```